# How to import own module within aws lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I am trying to import my own module but I am getting error:

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

`lambda_function.py`

[image]

Own module`name.py`

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images, but text formatted as code inside the question

Comment: @Tomerikoo seriously!!! you need text for this question.

Comment: I don't know if that's supposed to be a question or a statement. And no, I don't need anything, this is not my question. You on the other hand, want to allow people to help you easily. They can't copy-paste and run your code if it's in an image...

Comment: @Tomerikoo, Sorry sir In future question I will keep in mind. Actually I wanted to show all details like file structure, error log.

Comment: No problem, that's good and important. It's just better to put it in the question in a more readable way. I'm sure you'll agree with me that it's hard to see anything from these pictures. Good luck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You import it as if you were to import any other Python module. In other words don't do this:

`from .name import *`

but do this:

`from name import show_name`

For example:

[image]

The contents of `name.py`:

```
def my_name():
    print("Your name goes here.")
```

Don't forget to `Deploy` your function after making changes.

Comment: Why some editors induce us to make this mistake? It should be a standard feature in pylint, for example!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach that I find works well if your lambda function is a module is to save it as a module. So something like:

```
my_awesome_service
|--lambda_function.py
|--name.py
included_module_1
included_module_2
```

And then invoke using:

```
my_awesome_service.lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

Then the relative imports work and you don't need any changes to your code

Comment: This is a great approach, the unit tests in SAM CLI examples also work with this setup.